# how to fix ProvisioningDisabled for postgres flexible server

Tags: azure, postgresql, terraform

I am trying to create a flexible server of postgres and when I tried, the quota exhausted for eastus2. So I tried centralindia and got below error.

```
Error: waiting for creation of the Postgresql Flexible Server "testaksk8s-del-postgres-del" (Resource Group "testaksk8s-del-postgres"): Code="ProvisioningDisabled" Message="Specified Availability Zone not supported in this region."
│
│   with azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.example,
│   on 12-postgres.tf line 15, in resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "example":
│   15: resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "example" {
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error you received:

`Specified Availability Zone not supported in this region.`

Not all regions have AZ support. You can see which ones do [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview).

Edit: I see that Central India had AZ support added in December last year, so in theory this should have worked. I wonder if there's an issue with AZs there right now.